# Returning a Ruby Date object as a string in American MM/DD/YYYY format

Tags: ruby, date, datetime

I have a `Person` object that has a `date_of_birth` attribute, which is a Ruby date object.  My `Person` class has a `to_s` method, which returns all of the attributes from the `Person` as a string.

I want the `date_of_birth` to appear in MM/DD/YYYY format when `to_s` is called, but Ruby does YYYY-MM-DD by default.  Right now I'm using

`#{@date_of_birth.month}/#{@date_of_birth.day}/#{@date_of_birth.year}`,

but I was wondering if there was a cleaner/easier way to do this.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the documentation for the Date and Time classes, both of which support `strftime`. It's important to be familiar with the functionality of the classes of a language, so I recommend reading through the docs for the classes a couple times so you're aware of what's available making it easy to jump back to it when in need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use .strftime( ) method, like this:

```
@date_of_birth.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```